# .bash_profile conflicting with .profile preventing node from running

Tags: node.js, macports, rbenv, bash, .profile

I have my ruby environment set up in .bash_profile and MacPorts installed in .profile, as per its instructions.  I've installed node using MacPorts, but it seems like there's a conflict between .bash_profile and .profile.  Node worked upon installation, but it hasn't worked since unless I delete .bash_profile or load .profile in the terminal.

I'm still new to setting up environments, so I'm not sure if I can essentially combine .bash_profile and .profile to avoid this conflict or if there's a better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can move the modifications MacPorts requires to `$PATH` wherever you want. If that fixes the issue, move them to `.bash_profile`.

Take a look at the value of `$PATH` when your setup works vs. when it doesn't. I assume whatever ruby environment you are using is changing it in some way. Adding the following line at the end of your `.bash_profile` should make it work again:

```
export PATH=/opt/local/bin:$PATH
```